# Java gradle no service of type styled text output factory available in project scope service

Tags: java, gradle

When I build a project in console I have no service of type styled text output factory available in project scope service. I have also a file pom.xml .I don't know what I do it wrong

This is my build.gradle :

```
import java.sql.Wrapper

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management' 
apply plugin: 'war'


war {
    baseName = 'springboot'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("javax.servlet:jstl:1.2")
    runtime("mysql:mysql-connector-java")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/el-api
    compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'el-api', version: '2.2.1-b04'

    compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")
    providedRuntime 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper'
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe the problem is a function of the versions of Gradle and Spring's dependency-management-plugin that are in use.

See the original report from the Spring guys in this [Bug in Gradle 2.14-rc1 - No service of type StyledTextOutputFactory](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/bug-in-gradle-2-14-rc1-no-service-of-type-styledtextoutputfactory/17638) report. Gradle moved the `StyledTextOutputFactory` to an internal package at some point (for the 3.0 release), which broke dependency-management-plugin 0.5.x.

This [dependency-management-plugin issue](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/87) details their making changes to address this in their 0.6.0 release.

I see your build script references Gradle 2.3...but I'm wondering if that is accurate.

I think it boils down to either use Gradle 2.x with dependency-management-plugin 0.5.x or use Gradle 3.x with dependency-management-plugin 0.6.x.

Good luck.